# Issue in comparison different list in Scala

Tags: scala

I'm looking for a way to compare to different list types:

```
val a = List(event1, event2, event3)

val b = List(List(event1, event2, event3))
```

How can I compare these two lists for equality? I was trying nesting for loop, but I don't think that will work.

Comment: What two lists? I see one (or three??).

Comment: Can you explain how exactly you want to compare them? `a` and `b` are different things: `a` is (presumably) a list of `Events` and `b` is a list of lists of events.

Comment: It wasn't clear what you were asking since your code didn't compile. I edited it, but please verify that it still expresses your intent. Also, please see the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for tips on how to ask a good question.

Comment: If you already tried something, like "nesting for loop", you should include the code that your tried and explain what went wrong or where you got stuck.

Answer (score 1):

You can flatten your events list, so:

```
scala> List("e1", "e2", "e3")
res0: List[String] = List(e1, e2, e3)

scala> List(List("e1", "e2", "e3"))
res1: List[List[String]] = List(List(e1, e2, e3))

scala> res1.flatten
res2: List[String] = List(e1, e2, e3)

scala> res0 == res2
res3: Boolean = true
```